# Symfony2 processing configuration removes items

Tags: validation, symfony, configuration

I use Symfony2's `ConfigurationInterface` to validate the configuration within my bundle. I make use of its normalization methods so that I don't have to be checking for the existence of values when I parse the config myself.

This one method [ignoreExtraKeys](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/Builder/ArrayNodeDefinition.html#method_ignoreExtraKeys) has thrown me a curve ball. The docs state:

> Allows extra config keys to be specified under an array without throwing an exception.
>   Those config values are simply ignored. This should be used only in special cases where you want to send an entire configuration array through a special tree that processes only part of the array.

which led me to believe that those extra keys would remain in the resulting array. As it happens, they are not. I could define a rule for each key, but it would be impossible. This particular config file defines the structure of a form, the form types and options that should be passed to each type. There are just too many options to account for, it would neglect custom types and Symfony's Form builder already validates the options.

Before I go writing an extra method to merge those keys back into the array, is there any way to force the Configuration validator to leave the keys in place.

Ie. I would like it to validate and normalize what I configured it to, but to also ignore keys it doesn't know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible [an option](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/14238) will be added to the `ignoreExtraKeys` method in Symfony version 2.7.

For 2.6 and below the solution is a little cumbersome. First, the `variableNode` can be used for any data type with no validation. The data within these nodes remains in the output. The original `arrayNode` must be replaced with the `variableNode` then for each child which needs validating, a custom closure must be used with `validate`.

For example, existing code like:

```
->arrayNode('options')
    ->ignoreExtraKeys()
    ->children()
        ->scalarNode('sub-option')->end()
    ->end()
->end()
```

needs to be converted to:

```
->variableNode('options')
    ->validate()
        ->ifTrue(function($v){
            return !(is_array($v) && isset($v['sub-option']) && is_scalar($v['sub-option']);
        })
        ->thenInvalid('Wrong config')
    ->end()
->end()
```

This could be made easier by restructuring the configuration.